# Objects are not valid as a React child [object Promise]

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm new using reactjs. First case I want to get a json data from fetch url, but that json need async await to show all data. I managed to solve that problem, but now I want to append data from json to react return render. and then i get error like this **Uncaught Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: [object Promise]). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.**. This is my code

```
  async function URL(url, id){
    return fetch(url+"/"+id)
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((responseJson) => {
        const myArrayresponse = responseJson.image.split("/");
        return "https://myurl.com/"+myArrayresponse[2]+"/"+myArrayresponse[3];
    })
    .catch((error) => {
       return "images/icon.png";
    });
  }

const posts = datas[0].map((mydata, i) => URL(mydata.uri, mydata.id).then(img => {
      return `<a href={"https://myurl.com/"+CONFIG.ADDRESS+"?a="+mydata.id} target="_blank" className="mybtn"><div className="title">{mydata.name} ({mydata.symbol} - {mydata.id})</div><img src={img} /></a>`;
      })
    );
    
return (
<ResponsiveWrapper flex={1} style={{ padding: 24 }} test>
   <s.Container flex={1} jc={"center"} ai={"center"}>
       {posts}
   </s.Container>
</ResponsiveWrapper>
)
```

`const post` is [object Promise], how to append `const post` to react return render without [object Promise]?

Comment: almost same bro

Answer (score 0):

You get `[object Promise]` is because you are actually returning an array of promise.

So in order to get it works, you can to use `Promise.all` which takes an iterable of promises as an input, and returns a single Promise that resolves to an array of the results of the input promises. Refer here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all

You can do it this way:

```
  const [posts,setPosts]= useState([])

  async function URL(url, id){
    return fetch(url+"/"+id)
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((responseJson) => {
        const myArrayresponse = responseJson.image.split("/");
        return "https://myurl.com/"+myArrayresponse[2]+"/"+myArrayresponse[3];
    })
    .catch((error) => {
       return "images/icon.png";
    });
  }

  useEffect(()=>{
    async function getPosts(){
      const result = await Promise.all(datas[0].map((mydata, i) => URL(mydata.uri, mydata.id).then(img => {
        return `<a href={"https://myurl.com/"+CONFIG.ADDRESS+"?a="+mydata.id} target="_blank" className="mybtn"><div className="title">{mydata.name} ({mydata.symbol} - {mydata.id})</div><img src={img} /></a>`;
        })
      ));
      setPosts(result)
    };

    getPosts()
  },[])

return (
<ResponsiveWrapper flex={1} style={{ padding: 24 }} test>
   <s.Container flex={1} jc={"center"} ai={"center"}>
       {posts}
   </s.Container>
</ResponsiveWrapper>
)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).